# Getting errors while setting up Android.Support.V4.App.Fragments

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I am trying to setup fragments using Android.SupportV4.App.Fragments. This is my code so far:

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment PreviousFragment = null;

switch (CurrentFragmentNum)
{
    case 1:
        fragment = ShapeSelectionFragment;
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = ShapeFormationFragment;
        break;
}

switch (PreviousFragmentNum)
{
    case 1:
        PreviousFragment = ShapeSelectionFragment;
        break;
    case 2:
        PreviousFragment = ShapeFormationFragment;
        break;
}


var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
trans.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_in_left,
                Resource.Animation.slide_out_right, 0, 0);
trans.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
trans.Hide(PreviousFragment);
trans.Show(fragment);
trans.AddToBackStack(null);
trans.Commit();
```

Now let's just start with the first error on this line: `var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();` with the error:

> The name 'SupportFragmentManager' does not exist in the current
>   context

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should know android.support.v4.app.Fragment is different from android.app.Fragment,the inherited parent class is different

**android.support.v4.app.Fragment**:

```
var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
```

and the current class must extend **FragmentActivity**.

**android.app.Fragment**

```
var trans = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
```

only needs to extend **Activity**